# Inheriting from UActorComponent Error: Declaration must correspond to a pure virtual function

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am new to Unreal and I am confused as to why I am receiving an error in VS. I am currently using a class that inherits from UActorComponent, but whenever I try to override the TickComponent method I receive an error that says "Declaration must correspond to a pure virtual function in the indicated base class".

This is surprising to me because in UActorComponent has the following method defined in it's header:

```
virtual void TickComponent(float DeltaTime, enum ELevelTick TickType, FActorComponentTickFunction *ThisTickFunction);
```

my class inherits from UActorComponent:

```
class UClass :  UActorComponent
```

and I define my function as:

```
void UActorComponent::TickComponent(float DeltaTime, enum ELevelTick TickType, FActorComponentTickFunction *ThisTickFunction) override;
```

Why am I receiving this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of "UActorComponent::" in the declaration, that part belongs only when you are defining (implementing) the member and then only if you are doing so outside the class body.